# The Uri scheme is too long – AppSettings.config

Tags: c#

I received error here appConfig.Load(file); Do you know what should I do?

```
 string file = File.ReadAllText(baseDirectory + "\\test.config");

 XmlDocument appConfig = new XmlDocument();
 appConfig.Load(file);
```

AppSeting config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
```

Comment: "what should I do?" - at the least provide us an [mcve] rather than fragments of code where we have to guess what you're doing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I gave topic "The Uri scheme is too long" I show where I have got error and type of xml (App.config) what should I add more?

Comment: Check what the value of baseDirectory is. That string is too long, which might mean the variable was erroneously assigned.

Comment: @NeutralHandle I get correct file here  string file = File.ReadAllText(baseDirectory + "\\test.config"); problem is only with appConfig.Load(file);

Comment: I don't understand why this has an off-topic flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the uri as the parameter to the Load() method. You're passing the content of the file instead of the uri.